# Is there an output list of "sp_send_dbmail"?

Tags: database

I wanna know output list of `sp_send_dbmail`, for example when I run `sp_send_dbmail` and the output is `0` it was successful, also if the output is `20`, it did not find the recipients.

So I want to know if  there is a list of output for `sp_send_dbmail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ms190307.aspx), `sp_send_dbmail()` returns 0 if the process of sending mails could be started without error. This means, mails have been set in the database mail queue, and for every mail the `mailitem_id` for the message is returned in the result set.

Any return value other than 0 means error. The precise error code of the failed statement can be seen in `@@ERROR`.

After using `sp_send_dbmail()`, the mail is sent asynchronously and it still can fail for many reasons. So if `sp_send_dbmail()` returns 0, it does not mean final success.

You might look in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems` as in the case of error, the mails would be there (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1030781-23-1.aspx).

Comment: Ok, is there any way to know if the final result was successful?

Comment: To be precise, from my experience, no. You can do everything to create proper mails. Then you can do everything to put them in the queue. Then you can do everything that the server can work the queue properly. But at the end, you are not sure if a mail was captured in the spam filter. This is sending mails. But to do your best, I would check the result of `sp_send_dbmail()` (0 or not), then check the result set if there is an entry for every mail, then check `sysmail_faileditems`, if this is empty. Thus, you can say: "The mails have been properly sent, but if they have arrived I cannot know."

Comment: Ok, Reall thanks for you hepl, that helped me a lot. Again Thanks